# Notepad++ replacing xf6 to the original character

Tags: notepad++, utf-8

I open up my XML file (encoded as UTF-8 format) and it shows certain characters (öäü) as a black box including hexa number (xf6).

Is there any way to convert the characters to original and keep the file in same format (UTF-8)?

I need the format for further compilation of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually found an answer little later.

Step 1: Encoding -> Encode to ANSI

Step 2: Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8

Remind: the file was originally encoded as UTF-8.